# Proper RESTful way to create children in Laravel (Parent / Child) relationships

Tags: laravel, rest

Not sure this is specific to Laravel but what is the proper RESTFUL way to handle creating a child of a parent with Laravel.  For example I have a Car that can have many Drivers (`hasMany`) and Drivers belong to one Car (`belongsTo`).  If I want to create a Driver whose parent is Car #1 does the CarController.php have the responsibility to create the driver: `/car/1/driver/create` or do I use `/driver/create/car/1` and keep the responsibility within DriverController.php?

Right now I'm doing `/driver/create/1` (where #1 represents the Car) which feels wrong but I'm not clear about what the RESTFUL way should be.  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't a *proper* way of implementing nested resources in `REST` as it doesn't really care. There are arguments for and against nested resources, however, there are some generally accepted implementations and the agreement that whatever you decide on, be consistent.

I utilise nested resources, but only a single level of nesting and no more. So for example:

```
GET /cars/{carId}/drivers/{driverId}
```

However, I would avoid the following:

```
GET /cars/{carId}/drivers/{driverId}/incidents
```

If you have multiple nested resources, consider obtaining the nested resource *through* the parent resource:

```
GET /cars/{carId}/drivers/ // Get all drivers for the car
GET /drivers/{driverId}/incidents // Get all incidents for the driver
```

Arguably nested resource URLs can convey more meaning than a single resource URL at a glance. e.g.

```
GET /cars/{carId}/drivers/{driverId} // more meaningful
GET /drivers/{driverId} // less meaningful
```

With the second URL above, I do not know which `car` the requested `driver` is associated with until the resource is returned. That being said `/drivers/{driverId}` can still be applicable and useful to have depending on your use case.

A use case for a `/drivers` endpoint would be if you can create new `drivers` that are not yet associated with a `car`.

In response to your question of how to create a driver, I would consider the following use cases;

1. Create a driver without an association to a car

   - `POST /drivers`
2. Create a driver with an association to a car

   - `POST /cars/{carId}/drivers`
   - `POST /drivers`

For the `POST /drivers` endpoint you would use a `DriverController` and pass your `Driver` information to the `store` method. The validation rules in the `store` method would allow for an optional `car_id` parameter as part of the request. This would allow you to either associate a `driver` with a `car` at creation, or not.

For the `POST /cars/{carId}/drivers` endpoint, you would use a `CarDriverController` (or a `DriverController` in a `Cars` subfolder if often seen) and pass your `Driver` information to the `store` method. A `car_id` paramter would not be required in the request as the associated `car` would be obtained from the `{carId}` passed in the URL.

For updating your `driver` resources, you can follow the same principle just amending your HTTP verbs and creating the appropriate routes.

```
PUT /drivers/{driverId}
DriverController@update

PUT /cars/{carId}/drivers/{driverId}
CarDriverController@update
```

If you decided to implement both methods for creating `drivers` and you find duplicate code, consider refactoring it to a service.

**Update 1**

> For #2 POST /cars/{carId}/drivers is the store endpoint does that make GET /cars/{carId}/drivers/create the create endpoint? And similarly for POST /drivers creation endpoint GET /drivers/cars/{carId}?

If you're working with blade views and following the Laravel conventions then your form to create a new `driver` for a given `car` would be found at `GET /cars/{carId}/drivers/create` or `GET /drivers/create`.

> And it sounds like relationships should always get a separate controller.

Ideally yes as most applications are nothing more than CRUD and so everything can be mapped to one of the 7 controller actions. This keeps things clean and simple and responsibilities separate.

Take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF0jFKvS4SI) by Adam Wathan which explains how to map what you think are custom actions to one of the 7 basic Laravel actions. Bit lengthy at 40 minutes but well worth a watch.

Comment: Thank you that's very helpful!  For #2 `POST /cars/{carId}/drivers` is the `store` endpoint does that make `GET /cars/{carId}/drivers/create` the `create` endpoint?  And similarly for `POST /drivers` creation endpoint `GET /drivers/cars/{carId}`?  And it sounds like relationships *should* always get a separate controller.

Comment: @JSP I have added an update to my answer in response.

Answer (score 0):

POST /cars/1/driver.
no interest in specifying the action (create). the method (post) already does it.